# rendering dropdown dynamically vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm loading some data from server and than try to load `dimensionscodes` into Dropdown list using a Vue.js for-loop.

But when i try to select something from dropdown in first row , it will update all other dropdown list with that value, as you see here:

[image: ddlscreenshot]

How can i avoid this ? when i choose something from dropdown just update that dropdown not the others.

HTML:

```
<div id="app">
    <table id="tbl" style="display:none;" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Varenummer</th>
                <th>Beskrivelse</th>
                <th>Kategorier</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tblitems">
            <tr v-for="product in products">
                <td>
                    {{product.varenummer}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{product.description}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select  class="dropdown" v-model="selecteddimensioncode">
                        <option  value="">-- Vælg --</option>
                        <option v-for="code in dimensionscodes" :key="code.value" :value="code.value">{{code.text}}</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Vue.js

```
<script>
   new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data() {
            return {
                products: [],
                dimensionscodes: [],
                invoicenumber: '',
                selecteddimensioncode: ''
            };
       },
        methods: {
            fetchVarenummer: function () {
        $.ajax({
            "url": '@Url.Action("xxx", "xxx")',
            "method": "GET",
            "data": { "invoicenumber": this.invoicenumber },
            success: result => {
             
              $("#tbl").show();
                this.products = result.products;
                this.dimensionscodes = result.dimensionscodes;
            },
            error: result => {
                console.log(result);
            }
            });

            }
       }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, as you are using the same name `selecteddimensioncode` for all the dropdowns, it will be reactive and update all the dropdowns when changing one.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari alright, is there anyway make it dynamically '?! or how can i change this behavior!

Comment: Try using Vue.set to dynamically create the data property and then use those properties in select options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out i should use `v-bind:value="selecteddimensioncode"` instead of `v-model="selecteddimensioncode"` in this way its not going to reactive and update all dropdown.

```
<select class="dropdown" v-bind:value="selecteddimensioncode">
 <option value="">-- Vælg --</option>
 <option v-for="(code, index) in dimensionscodes" :key="index" :value="code.value">{{code.text}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same variable for all of your dropdown so on update it will change them all, I would recommend making a separate component for each dropdown ( instead of making more than one variable ) ,

goes somthing like this

#### dropdown.vue

```
<template>
  <select  class="dropdown" v-model="selecteddimensioncode" @change="handle">
       <option  value="">-- Vælg --</option>
       <option v-for="code in dimensionscodes" :key="code.value" 
                          :value="code.value">{{code.text}}</option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
     props : ['dimensionscodes'] ,
     data(){
        return {
            selecteddimensioncode : '' 
        }
     }
     methods : {
      handle() {
         if(this.selecteddimensioncode) this.$emit('selected' , this.selecteddimensioncode); 
    }   

  }

}
</script>
```

#### HTML

```html
<td>
   <dropdown :dimensionscodes="dimensionscodes" @selected="doSomthing" />
</td>
```

#### Vuejs

```js
<script>
 import dropdown from './dropdown.vue';
   new Vue({
      components : {
          dropdown,
     }
 ...
```